# Awaiting an RX subject in F#

Tags: f#, system.reactive

This is the same as [How do I await a response from an RX Subject without introducing a race condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458226/how-do-i-await-a-response-from-an-rx-subject-without-introducing-a-race-conditio), but in F#.

The C# solution looks like:

```cs
static async void Foo()
{
    var subject = new Subject<int>();
    var firstInt = subject.FirstAsync().PublishLast();
    firstInt.Connect();
    subject.OnNext(42);

    var x = await firstInt;
    Console.WriteLine("Done waiting: " + x);
}
```

My attempt in F# is this:

```fs
let foo () =
    async {
        use subject = new Subject<int>()
        let firstInt = subject.FirstAsync().PublishLast()
        firstInt.Connect() |> ignore
        subject.OnNext(42)

        let! x = firstInt
        printfn "Done waiting: %d" x
        return ()
    }
```

The `let x! = firstInt` gives the compile error `This expression was expected to have type Async<'a> but here has type IConnectableObservable<int>` so apparently C# does something under the hood that F# doesn't.

Is there a C# implicit interface cast at work here, that I need to do explicitly in F#? If so, I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: In F# there is no implicit interface casting you need to do  `x :> Iwhatever`

Comment: Out of interest, must you use subjects?  My understanding is that this is not recommended: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396449/why-are-subjects-not-recommended-in-net-reactive-extensions?rq=1 The points made about avoiding mutable state become more pertinent in F#.

Comment: @JohnPalmer: Problem is, I don't know what interface IWhatever should be in this case, or even if an interface cast is actually what's needed in this case.

Comment: @TheInnerLight: Not sure how else I should solve my problem, which is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394418/how-to-use-reactive-extensions-to-parse-a-stream-of-characters-from-a-serial-por , though in my case the input is a network stream instead of a serial port.

Comment: I don't see a description of the problem. Does your code not work somehow? How? Or does it not compile? What's the error then?

Comment: Sorry, forgot the most important info. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After further digging, it seems that C# calls `GetAwaiter()` under the hood when you `await` something. For a `Subject` or an `IObservable`, `GetAwaiter` returns an `AsyncSubject`, which isn't immediately useful in F#, but the `ToTask` extension method in `System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks` makes it useful. Apparently, you can apply `ToTask` directly to a `Subject` (or an `IObservable`) without going by way of `GetAwaiter`, so my problem is solved by changing the `let! x ...` statement to:

```
    let! x = firstInt.ToTask() |> Async.AwaitTask
```

edit:

### There's a better way

Using [FSharpx.Async](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Async/reference/fsharpx-control-observable.html) is a much better way of accomplishing the same thing:

```fs
open FSharpx.Control.Observable

let foo () =
    async {
        use subject = new Subject<int>()
        subject.OnNext(42)

        let! x = Async.AwaitObservable subject
        printfn "Done waiting: %d" x
        return ()
    }
```